# I get following error: '#FF000000' is not a valid value for Color

Tags: wpf

I sometime get following error message:

> Cannot convert the value in attribute
>   'Color' to object of type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Color'.
>   '#FF000000' is not a valid value for
>   property 'Color'.  Error at object
>   'HighlightTextBrush' in markup file

The WPF code for HighlightTextBrush is:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
  Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
```

Comment: Whoever thought that putting **brushes** into a class called System **Colors** needs a lesson in how not to name their classes. Preferably a painful one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are trying to assign a Brush to the Color property. You need to use:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
    Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextColorKey}}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem using CodeNaked's answer where it returned the same error. I used this instead:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
Color="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextColorKey},Path=Color}" />
```